# GetExitCodeProcess process termination status codes?

Tags: winapi, exit-code

Does anybody know where can I find a list of [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28VS.85%29.aspx)' process termination status codes? I've done some search in the internet and haven't been able to find one.

I'm receiving a 33102 code from a GetExitCodeProcess call and I don't understand why. I hope getting a description for this error code will help me sorting this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is application dependent. Contact the author of the application.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! A "compile silently" flag was killing me. Removing that temporarily exposed the problems.